# Connecting a promise through two services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm a bit new to angular and am trying to understand how I can use a promise with two services.

In the code below in the App.js I call FirstService.get(), which should wait for the RestService to return the result. In the App.js I would like to use the .then() to wait for the result from FirstService.get().

My question how do I need to set up the promise in the First Service so that I can use the .then() in the App.js?

Thanks!

```
// App.js
    FirstService.get().then(function(promise) {
         // do something here with the result

      }, function(response) {
        console.log('error');
    });

//First Service
oApp.service( 'FirstService', function( RestService, $localStorage, $q ) {
    this.get = function( ) {
        var url = o.buildServerUrl();

        // Retrieve info
        RestService.get(url, function(response) {
           return response;
       });
    };
});

// Rest Service
oApp.service( 'RestService', function( $rootScope, $http ) {

    this.get = function ( url, callback ) {
        try {

            $http.get(url).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    var response = o.processServerResponse(data, status);
                    callback(response);
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    var response = o.processServerResponse(data, status);
                    callback(response);
                });
        }
        catch(err) {
            var response = o.createExceptionResponse(err.message);
            callback(response);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
// App.js
    FirstService.get().then(function(promise) {
         // do something here with the result

      }, function(response) {
        console.log('error');
    });

//First Service
oApp.service( 'FirstService', function( RestService, $localStorage, $q ) {
    this.get = function( ) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var url = o.buildServerUrl();

        // Retrieve info
        RestService.get(url, function(response) {
           deferred.resolve(response);
       });
       return deferred.promise;
    };
});

// Rest Service
oApp.service( 'RestService', function( $rootScope, $http ) {

    this.get = function ( url, callback ) {
        try {

            $http.get(url).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    var response = o.processServerResponse(data, status);
                    callback(response);
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    var response = o.processServerResponse(data, status);
                    callback(response);
                });
        }
        catch(err) {
            var response = o.createExceptionResponse(err.message);
            callback(response);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: sweeet! Works well. Thanks very much, veritas1.